# Swift Firebase: List Firebase Children into UICollectionViewCells

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview

I have recently setup FireBase, but have not yet figured out how to embed the children of the "Posts" section into each individual UICollectionViewCell. Currently, the ViewController has this bit of code, where ipCell is the indexPath of the cell. What is returned is no description at all. I hope you can understand, since this has really been bothering me. The array posts is defined before.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FireBase
var posts = [String]()
var ipCell = Int()
var count = Int()
var description = String()
class HomeController: UICollectionViewController, 
UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
let cellId = "cellId"
var newCellN = Int()


let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Posts")



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    count = newCellN

    collectionView?.register(PostCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: 
cellId)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a 
nib.
}



override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return newCellN

}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout 
collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex 
section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 15.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
 cellId, for: indexPath)
    cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    cell.backgroundColor = .white /* #040504 */
    ipCell = indexPath.item
    return cell
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout 
collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width-20, height: 250)

}

class PostCell : UICollectionViewCell {
    override init (frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUp()

    }




    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    func setUp() {

        addSubview(profilePic)
        addSubview(TextF)
        addSubview(username)
        addSubview(descript)
        let screenW = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        TextF.frame = CGRect(x: 85, y: 5, width: screenW-110, height: 
48)
        profilePic.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 80, height: 80)
        username.frame = CGRect(x:85, y:40, width: screenW-110, height: 
22)
        descript.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 95, width: screenW-40, 
height:105)


    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    let profilePic: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "shadowcypher-1")
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()
    let TextF: UITextView = {

        let textV = UITextView()
        textV.textColor = .black
                    textV.backgroundColor = .white
        textV.toggleBoldface(nil.self)
        textV.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 24)
        textV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textV.isEditable = false

        return textV

    }()
    let username: UITextView = {
        let view = UITextView()
        view.textColor = .blue
        view.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        view.text = "@sonic"
        switch ipCell {
        case 0:
            view.text = "@timcook"
            break

        case  1:
            view.text = "@philschiller"
            break
        case 2:
            view.text = "@sundarpichai"
            break
        default:
            view.text = "@timmy"
            break
        }
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.isEditable = false
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.isScrollEnabled = false
        return view
    }()

    let descript: UITextView = {

        let desV = UITextView()

        desV.textColor = .black


 Database.database().reference().child("Posts").observeSingleEvent(of: 
 .value, with: {(snap) in


            if let snapDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
                var i = count + 1
                for each in snapDict{
                    let keyID = each.key
                    let childValue = each.value["post"] as! String
                    posts.append("\(childValue)")


                    print("\(posts)")


                }


            }

        })




        desV.isEditable = false
        let v = 0
        while (v < posts.count) {
            if (ipCell == v) {
                desV.text = posts[v]
            }

        }
        desV.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        return desV

    }()
}

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate a collection view with firebase data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37343882/populate-a-collection-view-with-firebase-data)

Comment: There are lots of similar posts https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bios%5d%20%5bfirebase%5d%20%5bswift%5d%20collectionview

Comment: No, I'm using subviews to setup my UICollectionView, would you kindly know how to do that?

Comment: It's unclear without the entire code. The code you provided is just to get data from Firebase, nothing about collection views.

Comment: Okay, I have updated the code above. The number of cells is retrieved from a different class, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you are coding or using nib/xibs to setup the cells. The process is pretty much the same as the one described in the linked questions.